# Scope of dependencies when exporting a module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When exporting a module that has another dependency, is it best to include that dependency within the module export function or outside of it? I usually see the latter, but it seems like it would be best to keep it in the local scope.

For example:

```
var foo = require('foo');

module.exports = function(d) {
    return foo(d)/2;
}
```

vs.

```
module.exports = function(d) {
    var foo = require('foo');

    return foo(d)/2;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only things exposed on `module.exports` and `global` can be accessed from other modules in node.  Unlike in the browser, `var` creates a *local* reference.  To quote from [node's documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node module **will be local to that module**.

The difference between the two versions is therefore minimal - the first incurs a lookup in the local scope, while the other [hits `require.cache`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_cache) every time the function is invoked. From what I have seen of node code, the former (`var someVar = require('something');`) seems to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! My understanding is that the lookup in the local scope happens only once - when the function is defined. Is that true? If so, the former method makes the most sense. Otherwise, do you know how expensive a lookup in the local scope is compared to a hit to require.cache?

Comment: The scope lookup is *likely* to be the less intensive one - the lookup is dynamic (IIRC) but is almost certainly easier for the JITC to optimize than the lookup for `require` + the function call + the lookup in the `require.cache`.